# Getter/setter with defineProperty

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to define a getter for my object. However, I also want to have the ability to point to a property of that setter.

Example object:

```
var obj = {
    weight: 14
};
```

Now I want to create a function that extends this object so when it's classically called as `obj.weight`, '14' will be returned. But, I want to also have to option to call `obj.weight.unit` and get 'Kilograms' in return.

This is what I tried to do:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'weight', {
    get: function () {
        return obj.weight;
    },
    'unit': 'Kilograms'
});
```

Getting the weight works, but getting the weight unit does not work. Also when I try to see the context of "obj" in the console, it just doesn't show "unit", as if it does not exist.

Comment: With what syntax do you intend to get the unit? `obj.weight.unit`? `obj.unit`?

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible. You cannot have a value be both a number and an object with a `unit` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bergi is right yet JS has these wrapper objects for primitives. Like the Number object. For your case I may come up with a solution as follows;

```js
var obj = { _weight : 14,
            get weight(){ var n = new Number(this._weight+"");
                          n.unit = "kg";
                          return n;
            },
            set weight(v){ this._weight = v}
          };
console.log(obj.weight); // returns a number object with PrimitiveValue  of _weight property.
console.log(obj.weight.unit); // returns "kg"

// however you can still use obj.weight just like a primitive number in operations.
obj.weight = 40;
console.log(obj.weight / 4)
console.log(obj.weight.unit)
```

Comment: ...so it's not impossible! ( what a crazy language! )

Comment: @Nick Perkins Yes there are many subtle points in JS such as when instantiated with the `new` keyword the arithmetic operators treat the `Number` object like a primitive while while you may freely attach them properties since they are objects in fact. To me this resembles the monadic behavior in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
var obj = {
    weight: 14,
    unit: 'km'
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'w', {
        get: function() {
            return obj.weight;
        }
    }
);
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'u', {
    get: function() {
        return obj.unit;
    }
});
console.log(obj.w);
console.log(obj.u);
```

You can refer to the document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty